# Pandas - Replace values in column with other values from the same column

Tags: python, pandas

**Dataframe** with 3 columns:

```
FLAG CLASS   CATEGORY
yes 'Sci'   'Alpha'
yes 'Sci'   'undefined'
yes 'math'  'Beta'
yes 'math'  'undefined'
yes 'eng'   'Gamma'
yes 'math'  'Beta'
yes 'eng'   'Gamma'
yes 'eng'   'Omega'
yes 'eng'   'Omega'
yes 'eng'   'undefined'
yes 'Geog'  'Lambda'
yes 'Art'   'undefined'
yes 'Art'   'undefined'
yes 'Art'   'undefined'
```

I want to fill up the 'undefined' values in the column CATEGORY with the other category value (if any) that the class has. E.g. The Science class will fill up its empty category with 'Alpha', The 'math' class will fill up its 'undefined' category with 'Beta'.

In the case there are 2 or more categories to consider, leave as is.
E.g. The english class 'eng' has two categories 'Gamma' and 'Omega', so the category 'undefined' for the class English will be left as 'undefined'

If all the categories for a class are 'undefined', leave as 'undefined'.

**Result**

```
FLAG CLASS   CATEGORY
yes 'Sci'   'Alpha'
yes 'Sci'   'Alpha'
yes 'math'  'Beta'
yes 'math'  'Beta'
yes 'eng'   'Gamma'
yes 'math'  'Beta'
yes 'eng'   'Gamma'
yes 'eng'   'Gamma'
yes 'eng'   'Omega'
yes 'eng'   'Omega'
yes 'eng'   'undefined'
yes 'Geog'  'Lambda'
yes 'Art'   'undefined'
yes 'Art'   'undefined'
yes 'Art'   'undefined'
```

IT NEEDS TO GENERALIZE. I HAVE MANY CLASSES IN THE CLASS COLUMN and cannot afford to encode 'Sci' or 'eng'.

I have been trying this with multiple np.wheres but had no luck.

Answer (score 2):

I will using `ffill` and `bffil` within `groupby`

```
s=df.CATEGORY.mask(df.CATEGORY.eq('undefined'))
s2=s.groupby(df['CLASS']).transform('nunique')
df.loc[s2.eq(1)&s.isnull(),'CATEGORY']=s.groupby(df.CLASS).apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill())
df
Out[388]: 
   FLAG CLASS   CATEGORY
0   yes   Sci      Alpha
1   yes   Sci      Alpha
2   yes  math       Beta
3   yes  math       Beta
4   yes   eng      Gamma
5   yes  math       Beta
6   yes   eng      Gamma
7   yes   eng      Omega
8   yes   eng      Omega
9   yes   eng  undefined
10  yes  Geog     Lambda
11  yes   Art  undefined
12  yes   Art  undefined
13  yes   Art  undefined
```

Comment: Would you change your code to be agnostic to the class values? I have many classes and cannot afford encoding the classes.

Comment: @Kaisar WenYoBen has `eng` got filled, but your output has it as `undefined`. Which one do you want?

Comment: @AndyL. Thank you for noticing. The post answer is to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

`df['CATEGORY']  = df.replace('undefined', np.nan, regex=True).groupby('CLASS')['CATEGORY'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0]) if not x.isna().all() else x).replace(np.nan, "\'undefined\'")`

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**:
I add another solution using `isin` to filter out on valid `class` for updating both `not undefined` and `undefined`. Then, updating this exact slice of `df`.

*Steps*:
Creating `m` as the series of `CLASS` has `CATEGORY` as `undifined` and unique `not undefined` values. Using `isin` to select qualified rows and `where` to turn `undefined` to `NaN`.  Finally, `Groupby` by `CLASS` on these row, `ffill`, `bfill` per group to fill `NaN` and assign back to `df`

```
m = df.query('CATEGORY!="undefined"').drop_duplicates().CLASS.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
df[df.CLASS.isin(m)] = df[df.CLASS.isin(m)].where(df!='undefined').groupby('CLASS').ffill().bfill()
```

This solution looks cleaner, but I don't know whether it is slower than original solution since using `groupby`

---

**Original**:
My solution constructs `'not undefined'` from `'undefined'` mapped by unique `'not undefined'` values:

```
m = df.query('CATEGORY != "undefined"').drop_duplicates().CLASS.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
t = df.query('CATEGORY == "undefined"').CLASS.map(df.loc[m.index].set_index('CLASS').CATEGORY)
df['CATEGORY'].update(t)

Out[553]:
   FLAG CLASS   CATEGORY
0   yes   Sci      Alpha
1   yes   Sci      Alpha
2   yes  math       Beta
3   yes  math       Beta
4   yes   eng      Gamma
5   yes  math       Beta
6   yes   eng      Gamma
7   yes   eng      Omega
8   yes   eng      Omega
9   yes   eng  undefined
10  yes  Geog     Lambda
11  yes   Art  undefined
12  yes   Art  undefined
13  yes   Art  undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do by using boolian indesing

```
df[(df['CLASS']=='Sci'& df['CATEGORY']=='undefined','CATEGORY')]='Alpha'
df[(df['CLASS']=='math'& df['CATEGORY']=='undefined','CATEGORY')]='Beta'
```

Comment: This is a vanilla example. I have thousands of classes values in the CLASS column. I doubt I can write a line of code per class.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you can rewrite a solution to be more general.